# Неправильно работают кнопки в PyQt6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt6

я пишу приложение в pyqt6 и оно состоит из нескольких файлов. но когда я запускаю мой код работает неправильно, а именно меняются только виджеты, а например фон программы не меняется.

вот код.

main.py

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from functions_for_main import FunctionsForMain

import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Quiz Application")
        self.resize(645, 500)

        self.functionForMain = FunctionsForMain()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.functionForMain.central_widget)

        self.functionForMain.quizApplication.start_button.clicked.connect(
            self.functionForMain.on_start_button_clicked
        )


def application_setup():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application_setup()
```

quiz_application.py

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget


class QuizApplication(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Quiz Application")
        # self.setGeometry(300, 50, 645, 500)

        self.welcome_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.welcome_label.setObjectName("welcome_label")
        self.welcome_label.setText("Welcome to Marathon Battle!")
        self.welcome_label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.welcome_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

        self.start_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.start_button.setObjectName("start_button")
        self.start_button.setText("Start Quiz")
        self.start_button.adjustSize()
```

functions_for_main.py

```
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets

from quiz_application import QuizApplication

class FunctionsForMain(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.central_widget.setObjectName("central_widget")

        self.quizApplication = QuizApplication()

        self.stack = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self)
        self.ix_stack_1 = self.stack.addWidget(self.quizApplication)

    self.QVB_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.QVB_layout.addWidget(self.stack)

    def on_start_button_clicked(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.setStyleSheet("""border-image: unset;""")
        self.enterOrRegister.resize_event(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(570, 450)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему. Что такое класс `EnterOrRegister()`? То что я вам писал в предыдущем вопросе, который вы удалили - актуально. Расскажите лучше, что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @S.Nick я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки у меня менялись виджеты и менялся задний фон, но это у меня не получается

Comment: self.functionForMain.enterOrRegister.register_button.clicked.connect(
`AttributeError: 'FunctionsForMain' object has no attribute 'enterOrRegister'`

Comment: self.functionForMain.login_window.back_button.clicked.connect( 
`AttributeError: 'FunctionsForMain' object has no attribute 'login_window'`

Comment: @S.Nick больше этой ошибки не будет

Comment: @S.Nick я так понимаю, что у вас не получилось решить мой вопрос?

Comment: нет, вы не правильно понимаете. Как-только появится время, я попробую посмотреть ваш вопрос.

Comment: я только что дал ответ на аналогичный вашему вопросу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1539581/  Попробуйте перестроить ваше приложение аналогично этому ответу. Если у вас что-то не получится с этим новым вариантом - зададите новый вопрос и покажите что вы пытались сделать.