# Как добавить функционал кнопке, который позволит переключиться на другое окно?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6, qtabwidget, qstackedwidget

Помогите описать функционал условной кнопки **`"PLAY"`**, который позволит перебрасывать пользователя на другое окно, где будут находится и другие виджеты, в том числе кнопка, которая будет возвращать в главное меню.

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel, QGridLayout, QFileDialog
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap, QCursor
from PySide6 import QtGui, QtCore

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle('first')
window.setFixedWidth(1000)
window.move(700, 200)
window.setStyleSheet('background: #161219;')

grid = QGridLayout()

image = QPixmap('logo.png')
logo = QLabel()
logo.setPixmap(image)
logo.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 
logo.setStyleSheet('margin-top: 100px;')

button = QPushButton('PLAY')
button.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
button.setStyleSheet(
    "*{border: 4px solid '#BC006C';" +
    "border-radius: 45px;" +
    "font-size: 35px;" +
    "color: 'white';" +
    "padding: 25px 0;" + 
    "margin: 100px 200px;}" +
    "*:hover{background: '#BC006C';}"
    )

grid.addWidget(logo, 0, 0)
grid.addWidget(button, 1, 0)

window.setLayout(grid)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Пробовал добавлять `QTabWidget`, но не знаю как скрыть эти кнопки переключения вкладок сверху, да и не уверен в том, что нужен именно этот виджет.

Comment: Используйте QStackedWidget вместо QTabWidget

Answer (score 1):

Класс [**QStackedWidget**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstackedwidget.html) предоставляет стек виджетов, в котором одновременно виден только один виджет.

```
import sys
'''
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel, QGridLayout, QFileDialog
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap, QCursor
from PySide6 import QtGui, QtCore
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Page1(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.logo = QLabel(objectName='logo')
        image = QPixmap('Ok.png')
        self.logo.setPixmap(image.scaled(200, 200))
        self.logo.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 

        self.button = QPushButton('PLAY', objectName='button')
        self.button.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
           
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.logo, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.button, 1, 0)


class Page2(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.logo = QLabel(objectName='logo')
        image = QPixmap('lena2.png')
        self.logo.setPixmap(image.scaled(200, 200))
        self.logo.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 

        self.button2 = QPushButton('Назад', objectName='button2')
        self.button2.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.button3 = QPushButton('Вперед', objectName='button3')
        self.button3.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.logo, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.button2, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.button3, 1, 1)
  

class Page3(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.logo = QLabel(objectName='logo')
        image = QPixmap('boy33.png')
        self.logo.setPixmap(image)
        self.logo.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 

        self.button2 = QPushButton('Page1', objectName='button2')
        self.button2.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.button3 = QPushButton('Page2', objectName='button3')
        self.button3.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.logo, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.button2, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.button3, 1, 1)
        

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.page1 = Page1()
        self.page2 = Page2()
        self.page3 = Page3()
        
        self.stackedwidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.stackedwidget.addWidget(self.page1)
        self.stackedwidget.addWidget(self.page2)
        self.stackedwidget.addWidget(self.page3)

        self.page1.button.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedwidget.setCurrentIndex(1))        
        self.page2.button2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedwidget.setCurrentIndex(0)) 
        self.page2.button3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedwidget.setCurrentIndex(2)) 
        self.page3.button2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedwidget.setCurrentIndex(0)) 
        self.page3.button3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedwidget.setCurrentIndex(1))             

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)    
        layout.addWidget(self.stackedwidget)


Stylesheet = '''
QWidget {
    background: #161219;
} 
#button, #button2, #button3 {
    border: 4px solid #BC006C;
    border-radius: 45px;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: 'white';
/* <----     
    padding: 25px 0;
    margin: 100px 200px;
*/
    min-width: 90px; 
    min-height: 90px;

}    
#button:hover, #button2:hover, #button3:hover {
    background: '#BC006C';                                          
}
#logo {
    background: '#161219';     
}
''' 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet) 
    window = Widget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Ok.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**lena2.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**boy33.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю, все получилось)

Comment: @АлексейВасин Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour